# Breakpoint on 3rd lib source can't be triggered when I terminate the program in IDEA

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, breakpoints, shutdown, quartz

I use **IDEA** as my java IDE and now I'm working on a program using springboot and quartz.
I set a breakpoint on the `quartz-2.3.0`'s source code `org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler` at line 585, and the breakpoint was enabled and was set to suspend on all thread without any specific trigger conditions.
[(A screen shot here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgThE.png)

Then I started the program, and the quartz scheduler began to work. Before the quartz scheduler finished, I terminated the program by pressing the stop button. Although the log printed the message that confirmed the code where the breakpoint on it had been executed. The program didn't suspend at the breakpoint. Is there anything wrong with it?

Here is the log

```
22:48:13.134 [schedulerFactoryBean_Worker-1] INFO  z.e.q.entity.dto.MyJob - Begin to execute job: DEFAULT.job_zyz2_1631439573107
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:57808', transport: 'socket'
22:48:23.090 [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler schedulerFactoryBean_$_DESKTOP-F3S0BUG1631458081508 paused.
22:48:23.419 [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] INFO  o.s.s.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean - Shutting down Quartz Scheduler
22:48:23.420 [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler schedulerFactoryBean_$_DESKTOP-F3S0BUG1631458081508 shutting down.
22:48:23.420 [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler schedulerFactoryBean_$_DESKTOP-F3S0BUG1631458081508 paused.
22:48:32.134 [schedulerFactoryBean_Worker-1] INFO  z.e.q.entity.dto.MyJob - Succeed to execute job: DEFAULT.job_zyz2_1631439573107
22:48:32.140 [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler schedulerFactoryBean_$_DESKTOP-F3S0BUG1631458081508 shutdown complete.
22:48:32.141 [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
22:48:32.144 [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Process finished with exit code 130
```

Comment: Try to stop your program from task manager, terminal's kill, or something else. I doubt the "stop" button stops the program only, and not the debugger itself.

Comment: On Linux this works for debugging shutdown hooks: `kill -INT <PID>`

Comment: I'm sorry I respond too late. Your options are constructive. My OS is windows10. And I can't terminate the process by command `taskkill /pid`. Finally, I write an additional http interface `/shutdown`, and let it execute the code `System.exit(1)`, and the breakpoint on shutdown hook triggered.